# why For loop not showing the right index number. a = 2 (should be 7) and l = 3 (should be 9) what i am missing here?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
let input = 'whale talk'
const vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

let resultArray = []

for (item of input.replace(' ','')){

    console.log(item + ' = ' + input.indexOf(item))

}
```

result

```
w = 0
h = 1
a = 2
l = 3
e = 4
t = 6
a = 2
l = 3
k = 9
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns the index of first occurrence. So, `a is at index 2` and `l is at index 3` which is the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for - of` iterates with the element's value. To deal with the element's index `for - in` can be used.

```js
let input = 'whale talk';
for (const index in input) {
    const item = input[index];
    if(item != " ") {
        console.log(item + ' = ' + index)
    }
}
```

Below is the result with correct running index of each element

```
w = 0
​h = 1
​a = 2
​l = 3
​e = 4
​t = 6
​a = 7
​l = 8
​k = 9
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you using loose equality over strict equality in your answers?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, loose equality ignores the type of operands `"0"==0 is true`, strict equality considers the type of operands `"0"===0 is false`.

Comment: Yes i know that but it's a bit outdated to use `==` instead of `===`

Answer (score -1):

As Wazeed said, indexOf always finds the first occurence of the searched value.

Since strings do have an `index` and a `length` property you can use a simple for loop:

```js
let input = 'whale talk'
const strippedInput = input.replace(' ', '')

for (i = 0; i < strippedInput.length; i++) {
  console.log(strippedInput[i])
}
```

If your `input` contains more than one space, you can use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` (or look into regular expressions for even more advanced stuff).